# sd values of kernels in kernel2D.R

Tags: r, kernel-density, spatstat

This question is concerning the `kernel2D.R` file in the `spatstat` sources, see https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/blob/master/R/kernel2d.R.

I would like to know how the `sd` values of the kernels in the `.Spatstat.2D.KernelTable` were calculated.

At first I thought that the given standard deviation should be something like

`$\sqrt{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (K(x,y))^2 dx dy }$`,

since the mean value is 0.
(I am sorry, but without reputation points they will not let me post an image of the rendered formula. Nevertheless, I think that my intentions are clearest if I simply post working LaTeX code.) But the results do not coincide with the given values.

E.g. for

```
quartic=list(
    d  = function(x,y, ...) { (3/pi) * pmax(1 - (x^2+y^2), 0)^2 },
    sd = 1/sqrt(8),
    hw = 1,
    symmetric = TRUE)
```

the formula above gives `3/sqrt(5*pi)` instead of `1/sqrt(8)`.

Then I saw that in the comments of `kernel2D.R` it says `sd = standard deviation of x coordinate, for standardised kernel`.

But I do not understand what this means. Can you provide the formula for the computation of these values?

---

I need this information because I am trying to use my own kernel functions as parameters to the `density.ppp` function. I would like to reproduce the results of `kernel = 'gaussian'` and `kernel = 'quartic'` with my own functions. As the bandwidth parameter `bw` for 'string kernels' is applied using `const = bw/sd` I have to adapt my self-written functions such that their `sd` value is 1 (because I do not provide them as a list, I think `density.ppp` can not handle that).
I know that if I multiply the kernel functions in `.Spatstat.2D.KernelTable` with `sd^2` and divide both `x` and `y` by `sd`, I get a correct adaption. (Simply because that is what happens if `bw = 1`). But I do not get where this comes from, in terms of the mathematical formula for `sd`.

---

BTW: I would like to say that I am very grateful for all the work that has already been put into `spatstat`, making it a most useful tool for me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I am sorry, this was stupid after all...

The formula for the standard deviation is missing an `x^2`. It should read

`$\sqrt{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 (K(x,y))^2 dx dy }$`

and then everything falls into place.

Sorry for bothering... =/